# OpenCV codes in Code Composer (CCStudio)

Tags: opencv, code-composer

I'm using CCStudio v5 to implement a vision system and want to use OpenCV functions in my code, but I don't know it is possible to use OpenCV code in CCStudio or not!

How I can import OpenCV library into my CCStudio project? Is this depends on my hardware?

Comment: Did you even try to google? Texas Instruments supplies a guide for compiling OpenCV on ARM Cortex-A8: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Building_OpenCV_for_ARM_Cortex-A8  What cpu do you use?

Comment: @PureW Thank you for your link, but my employers wants the systems deployed on a hardware without OS. Is it possible to use OpenCV source directly without building it?!

Comment: What hardware are you trying to build on? This document discusses different approaches depending on what hardware you have: http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/spry175/spry175.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official release of OpenCV for system without OS. OpenCV library is available for Windows, linux, mac, Android and Ios operating system.

[Here](http://www.societyofrobots.com/robotforum/index.php?topic=2278.0) 
you can find a link which explain the challenges of having OpenCV running on microcontrollers